# can't push/pull from mercurial repository - abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I am planning to use mercurial for a new project but I'm having some problem accessing the bitbucket repository. I'm new to mercurial, but I have used git previously.

I get the following error when peforing a hg clone or push:

*abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*

I only have this problem when using my work pc, when accessing the repository from my home pc I can clone and push just fine, any ideas, is there some firewall setting that needs to be configured?

I'm using Mercurial-2.1.2-x64 on windows 7 x64 for both pcs.

Comment: Are you using ssh or https (we cannot answer firewall questions with out this) ? Did you check with co-worker if they have the same problem ?

Comment: using https, no one else is using this repository yet. I will try and install mercurial on another work pc and see if I can access the repository from there...

Comment: Do you have the full log of a failed clone / pull ? If this is a firewall It could be a DROP rule for destination port 443 (and eventually you need to configure the proxy HTTPS is available).

Comment: i tried a clone with the -v --debug parameters and got the following error, is there a mercurial error log with more info?:  

using https://bitbucket.org/...  
proxying through http://bitbucket.org:None
http auth: user ..., password not set
sending capabilities command
abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: the strange thing for me is "password not set", try with http://user:password@bitbucket.org/repo/

Comment: no difference really  (just extra element in log: password ****), i also tried from colleagues pc and it worked fine for him, i also disabled windows firewall and that didnt help either.

Comment: Can you turn this into a question that someone might conceivably find by searching in the future?  Is there a general case here?  Your solution should go in as an answer (below) if you think it has general utility and should be closed/deleted if you don't.

Comment: done, I changed the title so its more relevant to the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the source of the error, I had initially installed tortoise hg which had created the following mercurial.ini file in my user directory, once I deleted this file, it resolved the issue. I suppose the problem was that I had specified the repository url instead of an actual http proxy...

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog


[tortoisehg]
cipushafter = 


[http_proxy]
host = https://****@bitbucket.org/****/*** (my repository path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the project folder in command prompt and run *hg rollback*.

Comment: TortoiseHg (Workbench) automatically rolls back on errors. If "clone" was canceled you don't even have a project folder...