# Pushing to Google Code Repository with Mercurial: "abort: error: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: mercurial, google-code

Mercurial used to work fine pushing to my Google Code repository, but recently, pushing has broken on my desktop at home. Every time I try to push to the repository, I get "abort: error: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

This is with Mercurial version 2.3.1. Neither my Mercurial.ini file or the project's hgrc file have anything entered under [http_proxy], so I know that's not the problem. Stranger is that pulling works without a problem. I even went as far as to uninstall and reinstall Mercurial, which did not fix the problem, either.

The only thing I can think of is that perhaps the amount of data I'm trying to push to the repository (6MB) is too large. However, I can push and pull both from my laptop, and my work computer. I've read these other questions and tried their solutions, but the problem still persists.

[Mercurial on Windows: abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554921/mercurial-on-windows-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-b)

[can't push/pull from mercurial repository - abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086576/cant-push-pull-from-mercurial-repository-abort-error-an-existing-connection)

[HG PUSH : abort: error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279767/hg-push-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote)

EDIT: installing Tortoise HG along with Mercurial has allowed me to push to the repository again, but I still don't know why it was broken in the first place. My best guess is that not having an [http_proxy] section somehow broke it, as would having incorrect settings.

Comment: 6MB shouldn't be too large - but I am curious, that isn't just a single file right?

Comment: No, it's a bunch of files, some in subfolders.

Comment: Does `hg push --debug` give any hints?

Comment: After further examination, it seems a connection is definitely established, and the operation seems to go smoothly until about 60% of the way through, after which I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your repository as a zipfile somewhere? It's possible you're tickling a bug inside Google Code's implementation of Mercurial, and it'd be nice to check that repository out.

I'd suggest opening an issue with a link to your repo at https://code.google.com/p/support/issues

Comment: Installing Tortoise HG has has allowed me to push again. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but I suspect that it had something to do with a bad config file that was overwritten.