# Clone of JFX8 repo fails to complete

Tags: mercurial, javafx, javafx-8

I'm interested in building JFX8 from scratch, potentially with some modifications, so started by cloning the relevant repo:

```
hg --debug clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt .
```

However, every time between around 5-10%, it fails:

> ...(snip)...
>
> files: 2087/40249 chunks (5.19%)
>   adding apps/samples/Ensemble8/src/samples/java/ensemble/samples/media/overlaymed
>   iaplayer/PlayerPane.java revisions
>
> files: 2088/40249 chunks (5.19%)
>
> transaction abort!
>
> rollback completed
>
> abort: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Am I missing something obvious here, or is there likely a problem with the servers at the OpenJFX end? If so, is there another way I can obtain the source?

Comment: According to [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279767/hg-push-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554921/mercurial-on-windows-abort-error-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-b) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086576/cant-push-pull-from-mercurial-repository-abort-error-an-existing-connection), the issue may be caused by an incorrect `http_proxy` configuration.  Have you verified that this is not the problem here?

Comment: @Vulcan Yes, there's no `http_proxy` configuration specified in my setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**openjfx repository mirrors**

There are [openjfx mirrors on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/openjfxmirrors), you could try checking out from there if you are having issues accessing the openjdk repository for JavaFX.

You probably want to work with the openjfx/8u-dev repositories rather than the openjfx/8 repositories.  The 8u-dev repositories are for ongoing development work where is the 8 repository is essentially closed because 8 has been released.  As it is quite new I don't think the Bitbucket mirror has been setup for 8u-dev yet.

**openjfx-dev mailing list**

In general the best place to ask about openjfx infrastructure and development related questions is the [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) mailing list.  That mailing list is regularly used by JavaFX developers and questions regarding development environment access and setup are frequently asked and answered on the list.  Also, if you are considering contributing to a new feature (such as [support for a variety of media codecs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22563941/1155209)), then the developers on openjfx-dev will be able to assist you in that endeavour (see [the JavaFX Media issues thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2013-August/009557.html) for an example of the kind of discussion which occurs).

Comment: Thanks, interestingly using the 8u-dev repo worked without issue, so I've just switched to that. Useful to know about the bitbucket mirrors though.